# React passing 'active' class to menu component

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I'm a noobie to React and trying to pass an "active" className to a nav component to reflect the current page. I can obviously o this with jquery, but I'm trying to learn the "right" way to do this within React.

Here is a non-working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/sku77tr0/12/) which I'm sure has tons of issues but is the core of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
//APP

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div id="app">
    <section id="nav">
        <TopNav />
    </section>
    <main>
      {children || 'Welcome'}
    </main>
  </div>
);

App.propTypes = { children: React.PropTypes.object };

ReactDOM.render(
  (<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/pageone" component={PageOne} />
      <Route path="/pagetwo" component={PageTwo} />
    </Route>
  </Router>), document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: This is pretty easy to do leveraging inline styles in React... Have you tried using the style prop?

Comment: Didn't know about that... will research it, thank you. Can my fiddle be (painlessly) modified to show me?

Comment: unfortunately I was unable to get your fiddle running

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames to conditionally join classNames. This will allow you to dynamically set styling based on events